# How do I dismiss an Alert Dialog in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, popup

I am using an Alert Dialog for the popups in my app. When the onTap is triggered the popup gets called however when I press the 'Cancel' button the popup does not dismiss and the whole screen behind the popup goes black. 
This is my code for the popup.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FancyAlertDialog {

  static showFancyAlertDialog(
    BuildContext context,
    String title,
    String message,
     {
    bool dismissable = true,
    Icon icon,
    @required String labelPositiveButton,
    @required String labelNegativeButton,
    @required VoidCallback onTapPositiveButton,
    @required VoidCallback onTapNegativeButton,
  }) {
    assert(context != null, 'context is null!!!');
    assert(title != null, 'title is null!!!');
    assert(message != null, 'message is null!!!');
    assert(labelPositiveButton != null, 'labelPositiveButton is null');
    assert(labelNegativeButton != null, 'labelNegativeButton is null');
    assert(onTapPositiveButton != null, 'onTapPositiveButton is null');
    assert(onTapNegativeButton != null, 'onTapNegativeButton is null');
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: dismissable,
      child: Dialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(4.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                ),
                color:Colors.red,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    child: icon ?? Container(height:0),
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 16.0,
                top: 2.0,
                right: 16.0,
                bottom: 8.0,
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: Text(
                      title,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  Text(
                    message,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(16.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          child: Text(
                            labelNegativeButton.toUpperCase(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: onTapNegativeButton,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                      Expanded(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(16.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text(
                            labelPositiveButton.toUpperCase(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: onTapPositiveButton,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how I've called the popup.

```
 FancyAlertDialog.showFancyAlertDialog(
              context,
              'Info Fancy Alert Dialog Box',
              'This is a info alert dialog box. This plugin is used to help you easily create fancy dialog',
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.clear,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              labelPositiveButton: 'OKAY',
              onTapPositiveButton: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                print('tap positive button');
              },
              labelNegativeButton: 'Cancel',
              onTapNegativeButton: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                print('tap negative button');
              },
            );
```

This is what my screen looks like when I press the cancel button:
[image]

Comment: where should I pass this?

Comment: i mean `child` parameter is deprecated, but anyway i run your code as it is (without any changes) and it works just fine - after clicking `cancel` or `okay` the dialog dismisses

Comment: Alright let me just check my other parameters that are being passed along with the popup in the onTap and try and see what's going wrong if its not the  popup that's causing an issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using the wrong `context` object when calling `Navigator.pop(context)`.
At that point the Navigator isn't aware of the dialog yet.

First, provide a new `BuildContext` within `showDialog`. There are two ways to do that:

- Create a new widget for the `child` parameter (now `Dialog`) in the `showDialog` function.
- Wrap the `child` (`Dialog`)  with a [`Builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html) that provides a new `BuildContext`

Then you should get that new `context` to the `Navigator.pop(context)` call. Again, there are two ways to do that:

- Pop from within the dialog itself
- Pass the context object along as a parameter to the `onTapPositiveButton` and `onTapNegativeButton`

More info on the `Builder` can be found here as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXNOkIuSYuA

Answer (score 7):

Try this inside your onTap():

`Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
```